# Django tests that should not run automatically

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am working on a sensor API and dashboard application using Django 1.9 and Django Restframework.

I have the usual unit tests that should run when I call `python manage.py test`.

In addition, I have two different types of tests:

a) Test connectivity to upstream data sources and API's.

b) Data consistency tests.

While unit tests should run in any context, a) and b) depend on specific contexts. I would like to invoke them manually, when this contexts are available (or should be tested).

I don't want them to run (and fail) whenever I call the management `test` command.

Any suggestions, how to create a test runner that would exclude certain test folders by default but runs them when explicitly called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The django solution can be like [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2211/)

You move context-dependent tests to separate app and exclude it. then implement this runner: `TEST_RUNNER = 'testing.simple.AdvancedTestSuiteRunner'`

```
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner #@UnresolvedImport
import logging
from django.conf import settings
EXCLUDED_APPS = getattr(settings, 'TEST_EXCLUDE', [])

    class AdvancedTestSuiteRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            from django.conf import settings
            settings.TESTING = True
            south_log = logging.getLogger("south")
            south_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
            super(AdvancedTestSuiteRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def build_suite(self, *args, **kwargs):
            suite = super(AdvancedTestSuiteRunner, self).build_suite(*args, **kwargs)
            if not args[0] and not getattr(settings, 'RUN_ALL_TESTS', False):
                tests = []
                for case in suite:
                    pkg = case.__class__.__module__.split('.')[0]
                    if pkg not in EXCLUDED_APPS:
                        tests.append(case)
                suite._tests = tests 
            return suite
```

When explicitly added to command, app won't be ignored `'python manage.py test south'`

---

#### Or use nosetests

They have categories

```
@attr(speed='slow')
class MyTestCase:
    def test_long_integration(self):
        pass
    def test_end_to_end_something(self):
        pass
```

From [docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html)

> -a=ATTR, --attr=ATTR
>       Run only tests that have attributes specified by ATTR [NOSE_ATTR]
>
> -A=EXPR, --eval-attr=EXPR
>       Run only tests for whose attributes the Python expression EXPR evaluates to True [NOSE_EVAL_ATTR]

Comment: Thank you for the help works like a charm. Posted the Django 1.9 update below (since DjangoTestSuiteRunner has been deprecated). However, the accepted answer goes to you @aershov.

Answer (score 1):

Here the Django 1.9 update, of that exact code snippet, I am using:

```
# from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2211/

from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
import logging
from django.conf import settings
EXCLUDED_APPS = getattr(settings, 'TEST_EXCLUDE', [])

class AdvancedDiscoverRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.conf import settings
        settings.TESTING = True
        south_log = logging.getLogger("south")
        south_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        super(AdvancedDiscoverRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build_suite(self, *args, **kwargs):
        suite = super(AdvancedDiscoverRunner, self).build_suite(*args, **kwargs)
        if not args[0] and not getattr(settings, 'RUN_ALL_TESTS', False):
            tests = []
            for case in suite:
                pkg = case.__class__.__module__.split('.')[0]
                if pkg not in EXCLUDED_APPS:
                    tests.append(case)
                suite._tests = tests
          return suite
```